# How to Populate CreatedOn and ModifedOn?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created model class and added logger fields `CreatedOn` and `ModifiedOn`. And I created A crud class for the same model. I want to handle this loggers without any form input filed and want to add to db table automatically. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I just said that I just begun with asp.net mvc 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I´m not sure what you mean excactly.   Wouldn´t you just populate these logger fields in your controller on post action?

(sorry if I´m misundarstanding)

Comment: I just started MVC so. I did the same. I added this values once the form model is validated after `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and its done. Thank you.

Comment: @Mohayemin actually I meant to comment on his question but I hastily used the answer box by mistake.  Anyway I´m glad you figured it out Rajan Rawal  :)

Comment: @gardarvalur: I just did not understand your answer. Since it is the accepted answer, no doubt its an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your preference/persistence model.

You can populate your CreatedOn property in the constructor and your ModifiedOn property on every save.

If you are using Entity Framework you can hook into the SaveChanges() method on the DataContext and populate your CreatedOn and ModifiedOn properties there. Make sure your properties are a part of a base class/interface like (IAuditable), then you can do something like

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
       ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        List<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntryList =
            ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added
                                                       | EntityState.Modified
                                                       | EntityState.Deleted)
            .ToList();

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in objectStateEntryList)
        {
            var auditObject = entry.Entity as IAuditable;
            if(auditObject.CreatedOn != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                auditObject.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            }

            auditObject.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```